# Iterate over records in mongo db and return a custom object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a mongodb collection with few records.
I want to iterate over the records in my collection and return a customObject.
For each record i want to do some computation over it and accordingly include an entry in my customObject if it fits my condition and then return the customObject finally.

I am doing it using mongoose.js

Say my record is

```js
Friends:{
  {name:"John", money_lent:100},
  {name:"Tom", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Tom", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Jill", money_lent:100}
  {name:"John", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Nate", money_lent:100}
  {name:"John", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Jill", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Nate", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Nate", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Nate", money_lent:100}
  {name:"Rob", money_lent:100}
  
}
```

I want to compute and object like and return to be used in my controller

```js
{
  {name:"John", times_money_lent:2}
  {name:"Tom", times_money_lent:2}
  {name:"Jill", times_money_lent:2}
  {name:"Nate", times_money_lent:4}
  {name:"Rob", times_money_lent:1}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends needs to be like

```
Friends: [...]
```

Because it's a list. The syntax I see in your question isn't valid. With Friends as list, you can do

```
Friends.map (function (friend) {
    return { name: friend.name,
             times_money_lent: friend.money_lent / 10 };
});
```

Or whatever

Comment: the records are saved in mongodb

Comment: Yeah, but you said you're using mongoose to retrieve them, and so now they're in your Javascript code, Right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already got your data fetched from mongo,then u can do the calculation like this:

```
var result = new Array();
Friends.map(function (friend) {
    var r = grep(result, function (val) {
        return val.name == friend.name;
    });
    if(r.length == 0) {
        result.push({name:friend.name, times_money_lent:1}
    } else {
        r[0].times_money_lent ++;
    }
});
```

Btw, you need to install `grep-from-array` in order to use grep! otherwise you need to implement the search function all by yourself.